# how redirect the output of command to graphical text editor

Tags: bash

I'm lost inside myself, so I'd like redirect output of command to graphical text editor (pluma).

```
cat test.sh > test_tmp && /usr/bin/pluma test.tmp
```

I need semplify operation redirecting "cat test.sh" directly to pluma

thanks

Comment: `/usr/bin/pluma test.sh` ?

Comment: http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html

Comment: In addition, you have a typo `test_tmp` -> `test.tmp`

Comment: Bad example (mine). I use a command to execute an operation, output of operation must be to redirect to pluma. Thanks

Comment: `pluma --help`? BTW what's wrong with a "temp" file? you *have to* store the edited file somewhere...

Comment: @anishsane: that edits the *script*.

Comment: So you want to view the script & then possibly save it as another file?

Answer (score 1):

Generalizing the concept you can use [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst), but I should point out that it doesn't work in every editor, in vim for example it does:

```
vim <(echo "outputting something from a script")
```

otherwise just make a temp file and then open it with your editor.

```
file=$(mktemp) && ./script > $file && pluma $file
```